# Dllregisterserver not found error

Tags: windows-7

I want to install a .dll using regsvr32. When I run the command:

```
regsvr32 "D:\Vehicle Recognition system\SDK And images (Dropbox Download)\cmanpr-8.31-x64-latin\w64\cmanpr-7.2.8.31.dll"
```

The following error is shown:

> entry point Dllregisterserver not found.

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Run command regsvr32 as Administrator, You can right click the cmd.exe file and select "Run as administrator". Then you can paste regsvr32 command

Answer (score 0):

This may mean the DLL you want to register is missing the bit that allows it to be registered. Try using `depends.exe` or `dumpbin.exe` (manual [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177429)) to see if the `Dllregisterserver` (described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) entry point actually exists in the .dll.

Perhaps you are just looking at the wrong .dll?